# How can I fix SQL Server 2008 orphaned columns RE: msg 3853

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, dbcc

I administer a SQL Server, but do not administer the actual application that runs on it. It is SQL 2008 r2 (10.50.1600.1) Recently when the company that develops and manages the application was deploying some updates they came to me with reports of corruption in the database and some output from `DBCC CHECKCATALOG` 
To wit:

```
Msg 211, Level 23, State 192, Line 1
Possible schema corruption. Run DBCC CHECKCATALOG.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should
be discarded.
```

Followed by a series of:

```
Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Attribute (object_id=1732409441) of row (object_id=1732409441,column_id=1)  in
sys.columns does not have a matching row (object_id=1732409441) in sys.objects.
```

and one:

```
Msg 3853, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Attribute (parent_object_id=1732409441) of row (object_id=323388817) in
sys.objects does not have a matching row (object_id=1732409441) in sys.objects.
```

I verified their results and figured out that these messages appear to be orphaned columns and an orphaned index from an old version of a table that has since changed in structure. The index doesn't appear in `sys.indexes`. The new table is in the database, and everything from an operations standpoint *appears* to be working fine (data is flowing, nothing seems out of place). But the vendor cannot complete their update due to this corruption.

We have done some digging on this and what we have found suggests that in SQL 2008 r2 and later you can no longer make direct edits to the `sys.objects` and `sys.columns` tables which I *think* would fix this issue as it appears to be just some orphaned columns and an orphaned index.

So my questions are two:

1. How can I clean this mess up? Is there a way to clear out the orphaned index and these orphaned columns or will I need to rebuild this database and migrate the data?
2. Any clue on how this would happen? (less important) The vendor recently did an update that made the structural changes to this table that are reflected in the orphaned columns versus the existant columns, but did not report any error to us at the time. I would like to put them on the hook for the cost of the fixes if they can be shown to be at fault.

Comment: You might find this link useful - http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-fixing-metadata-corruption-without-a-backup/

Comment: The key point from @Scott's link being `you can’t modify them unless you’re connected with the DAC and the server is in single-user mode.`

Comment: I had read that. Was hoping to avoid it as he seems to indicate that it would void any future support, and I would rather not put myself in that situation. But thanks for the link.